# SQL Statement won't work anymore after small change. VBA

Tags: sql, database, oracle, vba

this Statement works totaly fine in ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER, but when I insert it to my vba makro it won't return me my BLOB files from the database. The statement worked before in VBA with a data-number variable instead of referencing to SYSDATE...

Provider is OraOLEDB.Oracle, the Connections string "works/opens" but there is no data to pass my - IF rs.EOF = FALSE Then -  I've already tested eof=true but no data comes through....Any ideas ? thx!

```
select datas 
from tdb 
INNER JOIN  (select datas_id 
         from tfdz 
         INNER JOIN (select fb_id 
                    from tfb 
                    INNER JOIN (select pu_id 
                                from tpu 
                                INNER JOIN (select tap.p_id 
                                            from tap 
                                            INNER JOIN (SELECT po_id
                                                        FROM tpo
                                                        WHERE tpo.lastdate like (SYSDATE-1)
                                                        ) sub_tpo
                                            ON tap.po_id = sub_tpo.po_id and tap.lastdate like (SYSDATE-1)
                                            ) sub_tap 
                                            ON tpu.p_id = sub_tap.p_id 
                                ) sub_tpu 
                                ON tfb.pu_id = sub_tpu.pu_id 
                                where tfb.deleated = 0
                    ) sub_tfb 
                    ON tfdz.fb_id = sub_tfb.fb_id 
          ) sub_tfdz 
          ON tdb.datas_id = sub_tfdz.datas_id 
order by sub_tfdz.datas_id asc
```

Comment: Can you try trunc(tpo.lastdate) like (trunc(SYSDATE)-1)

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see how you are passing it, I assume as a string, have you tried.

```
WHERE tpo.lastdate like (" & Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Now()), "DD/MMM/YYYY") & ")"
```

You may need to change the format to be compatible Oracle date processing

Comment: couldn't get your codesnipp running yet.When developing I couldn't find a correct Syntax for the Date Functions only SYSDATE worked in SQL Developer. 


"WHERE upper (tpo.tonbr)= UPPER('DATANUMBERVARIABLE') "- passes my IF and outputs Blob data from database to vba

Comment: run `select sysdate from dual` in oracle.  Note the format it gives you, replicate it in Excel so that when you pass it it makes sense (or just pass it in the format yyyymmdd which will usually work)